# Returning one row if the value is shown twice

Tags: php, mysql

**Why the down-vote on the question?**

So I'm working on a project that will show the registered users, and if a registered user has a product in another mysql table, the users' email will be shown in another list, but only once.
In the database the users email is the binding point with each product, so if a user has 2 products the email will be set twice in the database but on two different rows.

 So what I need to do here is to hide one row if the email is given twice.

is this possible with some changes to the mysql or is it possible to modify the statement with a php if statement, if so how?
 The LIMIT 1 doesn't seem to work in this query.

The code below shows:
mail@aaa.com
mail@aaa.com
mail@aaa.com
mail@bbb.com
mail@ccc.com

I want it to show:
mail@aaa.com
mail@bbb.com
mail@ccc.com

With thanks
Jim

```
<?php 
    $user_list = "";
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userproducts");
        $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        if ($userCount > 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $email = $row["user"];

                $user_list .= '<table width="300">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>'.$email.'</td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>';
            }
        }else{
                $user_list = "We have no users with special prices yet";
        }
?>
```

Comment: [Distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) might help you

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks mate, I'm actually aware of this and learning at the moment.

Comment: I'm curious, why the down vote on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a GROUP BY to the query

```
SELECT * FROM userproducts GROUP BY user
```

Or use DISTINCT to fetch the unique users

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user) FROM userproducts
```

Comment: GROUP BY with `*` won't work cause ID will be aggregated, has to be `SELECT user FROM userproducts GROUP BY user`

Comment: Thanks this works, I've not tried the DISTINCT yet, i will try it.. However what is the difference between the two? Others seem to prefer DISTINCT over GROUP BY.

Comment: @mirkobrankovic I just tried with * and it works for me using GROUP BY.

Comment: We'll, normally you use DISTINCT to select the unique values from the database and GROUP BY when using aggregrate operators (AVG, MAX, MIN, etc). But in this case, both will word

Comment: When this helped you, can you please select this answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: @Benz I've tried to select it as accepted answer already, however i can't yet, it tells me to wait a few more minutes. Thanks for the explanation on the differences.

Comment: while it is not standard SQL, MySQL allows you to group by a column (user) while selecting all columns. The value of all other non aggregated columns will be undetermined, but it might be correct in this situation... of course if you only need the user, it's better to SELECT user FROM userproducts GROUP BY user

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user) FROM userproducts
```

in query.